# fread and fwrite with pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write an array of structures to a binary file but when I call the function fwrite does not save anything in the file.

In the structure they are saved correctly

```
void Escribir_swap(const char *PCB, const char *Archivo, Pagina **Paginas){
FILE *A, *B;
char exeption[5] = " \n\t,";
char LINE[LONG_MAX_LINE];
int TAM = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < MARCOS; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < PAGINAS; j++){
        if(Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A) !=NULL ){
            strcpy(Paginas[i][j].Instruccion,Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A));
            strcpy(Paginas[i][j].register1, Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 1));
            strcpy(Paginas[i][j].register2, Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 2));
            TAM++;
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
      }
    }
printf("I\t R1,R2\n");
for(i = 0; i<MARCOS; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<PAGINAS; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\t %s,%s\n", Paginas[i][j].Instruccion, Paginas[i][j].register1, Paginas[i][j].register2);
    }
}
if(B = fopen(Archivo, "wb")==NULL)
{

    printf("Error al abrir archivo %s", Archivo);
    perror(Archivo);
}else
{
    for(i = 0; i<MARCOS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",fwrite(Paginas[i], sizeof(Pagina), PAGINAS, B));//here shows segment violation!!!!
    }
}
fflush(B);
fclose(B);
```

}

Comment: printf .......?

Comment: 'if(B = fopen(Archivo, "wb")==NULL)' ... 'B' is assigned a boolean result.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @MartinJames  Thank you!

Comment: @JuanJ.Mart you can thank me by not writing compound expressions/statements:)  So many times this goes wrong:(  Simple code with many intermediate results is safer and easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

The first argument for fwrite is a FILE*. You must have turned lots of warnings off or your compiler would have told you.

Comment: `size_t fwrite(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`